# Edit text format with shell script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-interface, sh

I am trying to make a script for text editing. In this case I have a text file named text.csv, which reads:

```
first;48548a;48954a,48594B
second;58757a;5875b
third;58756a;58576b;5867d;56894d;45864a
```

I want to make text format to like this:

```
first;48548a
first;48954a
first;48594B
second;58757a
second;5875b
third;58756a
third;58576b
third;5867d
third;56894d
third;45864a
```

What is command should I use to make this happen?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: In your first line of input data, is the last separator supposed to be a comma, or a semicolon?  Or do you want to accept *either* character as a separator?  (The answer might affect how tools are used to split your data.)

Comment: hi Jordanm, I just try to use awk command but I do know how to make it happen, thats why I asking what is command should I use.. :D .. by the way thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do this in awk.

Assuming your first line should have a `;` instead of a `,`:

```
$ awk -F\; '{for(n=2; n<=NF; n++) { printf("%s;%s\n",$1,$n); }}' input.txt
```

Untested.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure bash solution that handles both `,` and `;`.

```
while IFS=';,' read -a data; do 
   id="${data[0]}"
   data=("${data[@]:1}")
   for item in "${data[@]}"; do 
      printf '%s;%s\n' "$id" "$item" 
   done
done < input.txt
```

UPDATED - alternate printing method based on chepner's suggestion:

```
while IFS=';,' read -a data; do 
   id="${data[0]}"
   data=("${data[@]:1}")
   printf "$id;%s\n" "${data[@]}" 
done < input.txt
```

Comment: Or `printf "$id;%s\n" "${data[@]}"`; no for loop necessary.

Comment: @chepner - That is a good suggestion. I usually don't like expanding variables in printf's format string, but it does save a loop.

Answer (score 1):

`awk -v FS=';' -v OFS=';' '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) { print $1, $i }}'`
Explanation: awk implicitly splits data into records(by default separeted by newline, i.e. line == record) which then are split into numbered fields by given field separator(`FS` for input field separator and `OFS` for output separator). 
For each record this script prints first field(which is record name), along with i-th field, and that's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS=';,' read -a data; do 
   id="${data[0]}"
   data=("${data[@]:1}")
   printf "$id;%s\n" "${data[@]}" 
done < input.txt
```

or

```
awk -v FS=';' -v OFS=';' '{for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) { print $1, $i }}'
```

And

```
$ awk -F\; '{for(n=2; n<=NF; n++) { printf("%s;%s\n",$1,$n); }}' input.txt
```

thanks all for your suggestions, :d. It's really give me a new knowledge..

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, it should include something that was not already posted as an answer. Instead of reposting the answers, you should upvote them and select one to "accept". Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).