# Edit Text format (probably with shell script)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to write a script to edit the format of  a text file. I got a file with coordinates in the form

```
x: 123
y: 456
x: 789
y: 012
...
```

but need it in the form

```
123 456 i
789 012 i
...
```

Kind of like here [Edit text format with shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838016/edit-text-format-with-shell-script), just the other way round and a little more ;)

Do u guys have any ideas how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple bash script using a counter to toggle printing after read of every 2 lines can suit your need. Just pass the data file as argument 1:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i cnt=0

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    array+=( ${line##* } )                              # read values into array
    ((cnt++))                                           # increase counter
    if [ "$cnt" -eq 2 ]; then                           # if count = 2
        printf "%s %s i\n" "${array[0]}" "${array[1]}"  # print both array values
        cnt=0                                           # reset count to 0
        unset array                                     # unset array
    fi
done <"$1"
```

**output**

```
123 456 i
789 012 i
```

Comment: Just FYI .. when you use `declare -i` you can write `cnt+=1` as well without the `((..))` construct.

Comment: Now that is a good bit of learning, added to bash toolbox! (well basket file)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
awk 'NR>1&&NR%2{print a[1],a[2],"i";i=0}{a[++i]=$2}END{print a[1],a[2],"i"}' file
```

The array `a` contains the contents of the previous two lines. Ignoring the first line, when the line number is odd (i.e. when `NR%2` is 1), print the last two lines, followed by "i". At the end, print the last two lines.

Testing it out:

```
$ awk 'NR>1&&NR%2{print a[1],a[2],"i";i=0}{a[++i]=$2}END{print a[1],a[2],"i"}' file
123 456 i
789 012 i
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1 == "x:"{line=$2}$1 == "y:"{line=line FS $2 FS "i"; print line}' file
123 456 i
789 012 i
```

Alternatively, a `read` loop:

```
while read -ra line; do
    case ${line[0]} in 
        x:)
            new_line=${line[1]}
            ;;
        y:)
            new_line+=" ${line[1]} i"
            echo $new_line
            ;;
    esac
done < file
```